# Why might my Mongoose connection close in-between calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

So I have a test that tries to signup with the same email twice, at which point I am relying on Mongo's unique constraint to throw an error. If I run the query twice manually I get the correct error however, in my test I get a different error: **"MongoError: server is closed"** when the second call tries to run **.save** on that instance of the User model. I am using Node.js, Express, Mongoose and Mocha.

I have a beforeEach function that drops the collection and rebuilds the index before each test but I have put a console log in that proves it's not running in-between model calls, only once at the start as expected. So why might my connection be closing? I seen some blogs suggesting I up the pool size but I tried that and it made no difference :/

My test code...

```
// Check no email dupes is being enforced
it("should throw when we try to add user with dupe email", () => {
    assert.throws(async () => {
        await User.addNewUser({
            name: "Mandy  ",
            email: "  Mandy@iscool.com",
            password: "password",
        })
        await User.addNewUser({
            name: "Mandy  ",
            email: "  Mandy@iscool.com",
            password: "password",
        })
    })
})
```

My model code...

```
userSchema.statics.addNewUser = async function (params) {
    const randomSlug = cryptoRandomString({length: 64,  type: "url-safe"})
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(params.password, 10)
    const user = new User({
        name: params.name,
        email: params.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        active: false,
        activationCode: randomSlug
    })
    await user.save()
    return randomSlug
}
```

Comment: Is `assert` from the built-in `assert` module in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert.throws` is for asserting that errors are synchronously thrown from a function. Use [`assert.rejects`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message) to detect an *asynchronous* function returning a Promise that is rejected:

```
it("should throw when we try to add user with dupe email", async () => {
  await assert.rejects(async () => {
    await User.addNewUser({
      name: "Mandy  ",
      email: "  Mandy@iscool.com",
      password: "password",
    })
    await User.addNewUser({
      name: "Mandy  ",
      email: "  Mandy@iscool.com",
      password: "password",
    })
  })
})
```

What is probably happening to you is that `assert.rejects` runs your async function but just gets back a Promise; then the test passes because it's not waiting for the async stuff to complete, and your test suite is likely closing the connection. Then, after that first `await` completes, the connection is closed, and your second `addNewUser` fails.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I switched out .throws for .rejects but that still gets the wrong error. The production version of my code generates an error "E11000 duplicate key error collection" when I try to add a duplicate. The test version gets "server is closed".

Comment: You're awaiting the `assert.rejects` call?

Comment: Just noticed that await you put in! It works fine now, thanks a million :)